# Are there Optional variables in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, option-type

**I enjoy using the new [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class in Java. Is there an equivalent in Objective C?**

I need something that can hold a small value like `nil` until I try to get its value, at which point it is initialized and has the new value cached for next time I read it. I don't want to check if the object is `nil` at every point where I try to read its value.

Comment: Sounds like a property that is lazy loaded. That's easy in Objectve-C by implementing your own getter method.

Comment: @rmaddy what about without creating a whole new class? This will be for a `NSString`

Comment: Coming from Haskell, I was disappointed that most c-based languages don't have Option types. They're all sorts of useful.

Comment: Obj-C doesn't have generics or templates so it cannot have typed optionals. Otherwise there is nothing difficult about implementing an optional

Comment: Optional does not behave as you describe. Firstly it doesn't create an instance on your behalf. Secondly it doesn't free you from checking for nil - in fact it does just the opposite. I think what you are asking for is something more like `Lazy<T>` in C#.

Comment: @jaket that sounds about right, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lazy load the variable using a getter.

```
- (MyClass *) something {
    if(!_something) {
        _something = [MyClass new];
    }
    return _something;
}
```

Thus, each time you use `instance.something`, it will do the checking for you and load the object if it's not there already.

If it's a simple one-liner and you simply don't want to use `if`, you can skip out the keyword (I hear this is quicker, but can't verify that now):

```
- (MyClass *) something {
    return _something ?: (_something = [MyClass new]);
}
```

Comment: This is my current solution, but I don't like the idea of checking that `if` every single time, when in reality it only needs to be checked the first time, because after that, it will always be skipped.

Comment: Ben, I updated this. Fundamentally, some bit of code has to do the work, even if you don't write it. I suppose you could write a macro for this, but it sounds a bit like overkill to me.

Comment: That sentence had been nagging at me for years, and one day I came up with this solution for Swift, which uses function swapping so the first time it generates and stores the value, and subsequent times it just returns the value from the first time without checking: https://github.com/RougeWare/Swift-Lazy-Patterns/blob/b43e447be78ac63fb2e62a7cccd71cda7ac02c46/Sources/LazyContainers/LazyContainers.swift#L332-L442

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the unwrapping in Swift where `myObject?.aValue` will return `aValue` only if `myObject != nil`. Or the `if let` statement: `if let value = myObject?.aValue`

In objective C, there is no specific syntax dedicated to this however you can easily test for existence using simple if statement e.g.: `if(myObject)`. Because Objective-C objects are pointers and the address of a NULL pointer is 0x0 this if statement will evaluate to false if `myObject` is NULL (or nil if you like).

If you try to read a property of a nil object you will likewise get `nil` (for properties that are also objects). And if you try to set a nil object's property, nothing will happen.

I like to use the ternery operator as much as possible e.g.:`string != nil ? [textField setText:string] : NULL;`

As suggested in previous answers you can use lazy instantiation in your specific situation.

Comment: Java also has no dedicated syntax to this, which is why I used its `Optional` class as an example; I was hoping such a class (NSOptional?) might exist